# Keep Input Date Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, submit

I am choosing a date with submit. What I want to do is keeping this date on the form when I am redirected to another web page.

https://jsfiddle.net/92gd7v26/

I tried this but it's not working:

```
$name7=$_SESSION['date'];
$name8=$_SESSION['date2'];
$name9=$_SESSION['date3'];

<script>// <![CDATA[
$( function() { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker(); $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker(); 

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,

    })
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",   $name7);
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate",  $name8);
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker("setDate",  $name9);
} );
// ]]></script>
```

I don't know what's wrong. I am able to get the "date" values from $name7,$name8 and $name9. But when I try to put them on .datepicker("setDate") I am not getting the values I sent..

Comment: check the date format.  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' is the datepicker default date format.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Show what is the value of $name7,$name8,$name9

Comment: The value of $name7,$name8 and $name9 is the value I want. I can use this: $name7= date('m/d/Y',strtotime($name7)); to format the date. I have tried all the formats and the date shown on the submit is always 09/09/2016.

Comment: date('yy-mm-dd',strtotime($name7))try this

Comment: I did but if I echo $name7 after this when I choose 09/23/2016 i get : 1616-0909-2323  xDDD. On the submit always the same value: 09/09/2016

Comment: What is the value being written to the page when you view the source of the page?

Comment: I need to solve this. I am trying to change the code. I have this:  <input id="datepicker" name="date1" type="text" value='02/02/2016'>. With this code when I try to choose a date I got 02/02/2016 by default. Now, What I want is  the value on my variable $name2 to be put on there. If I print $name2 i Have 02/02/2016 but somehow, the "value" of the input doesn't accept variables.